# Jetty client / server mutual authentication

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, keystore, truststore

I am trying to build a client / server servlet application with these general requisites:

- both the client and the server are jetty embedded;
- the server expose a servlet in order to receive json data via `POST`;
- the connection must be secured via SSL (i.e. the connection will be done via Internet via https);
- I want that **only** my Jetty client be able to send data to my server, all other tentative must be refused by the server;
- the server and the client are unattended machines (i.e. not password via command line could be inserted by human);
- no password in clear must be stored on the client device. In general I don't want someone could open the remote client device and stole the password and building a fake remote device capable to send data to my server too.

I have build a perfectly working client / server application via `HTTP` but I am confused about the security.
I have read that there is the possibility to use client / server mutual authentication and seems  what I am looking for but I can't get the complete picture.
In this document [client-certificate-authentication](https://gist.github.com/jankronquist/6412839) there is a more or less clear explanation about how to build a *shared trusted CA* but the password for accessing the `TrustStore` and the `KeyStore` are in clear in the code.
I think I am missing a tile in the puzzle.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

S.

Comment: You are asking many questions here.  how to ensure only my client can talk, how to do SSL/TLS client certificates, how to secure the client certificate details, etc.  This will take a while to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going with a simple answer (for now).

If you just want only your clients to talk to the server, then yes, Client SSL/TLS certificates are the way to go.

You'll want the server's `SslContextFactory.Server.setNeedClientAuth(true)` set to true.  That will in turn cause Java's `javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters.setNeedClientAuth(true)` to be set on incoming connection establishment.  If the client fails to provide the client certificate, the connection is closed, and no HTTP request is sent or processed.

As for securing the client certificate, that's up to you, you can do anything you want to do, as long as it results in a valid client `SslContextFactory.Client` that the Jetty client can access.  This includes ...

- Using plaintext passwords
- Using [obfuscated passwords](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security-secure-passwords.html) (minimal effort, minimal security)
- Encrypted keystore/truststore passwords elsewhere in your client, provided to the SslContextFactory.Client at the last minute. (modest security, wouldn't be that hard to figure out)
- Creating the `java.security.KeyStore` object yourself and handing it to `SslContextFactory.Client.setKeyStore(KeyStore)` and `SslContextFactory.Client.setTrustStore(KeyStore)` methods prior to starting the Jetty Client. (a bit better security wise, puts more work on your behalf)

You might want to consider having the client certificates be short-lived (24 hours?) dynamically refreshed from the server, and have the client certificates be revokable (at the server/CA side) if you encounter abuse. (such as the same client certificate from multiple different client IPs)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, I will study it carefully. 
I was reading about the KeyStore but what puzzle me is that for opening the Keystore I have to provide to Jetty a password that I have to write somewhere (obfuscated or not) on the file system (correct me if I'm wrong). So as far as I have understood the KeyStore is secure but if someone stole the password from the file system could get the secure information in it and impersonate a fake client. or not?